# How to get const asserted value from an object

Tags: typescript

```
const obj1 = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2'
} as const;

const obj2 = {
    key3: `${obj1.key1}-test`,
    key4: `${obj1.key2}-test`
} as const;

type MyType = typeof obj2.key3 | typeof obj2.key4
```

Here, because of interpolation, MyType becomes `string` type instead of `val1-test | val2-test` type. What should I do here to get the desired typing without duplicating values?

Comment: You can't — TypeScript cannot determine the values of computed string literals in compile-time.

Comment: @KarolMajewski ok I was expecting it to work because I had const assertion added to obj1 declaration. Does that not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot determine what the value of a computed string literal will be.

Using the `as const` assertion will narrow the types within `obj1`. However, TypeScript will not go as far as to try and compute the runtime result in `obj2`.

Keep in mind that const assertions are purely a compile-time feature. Nothing stops you from overriding the values in runtime. Consider this:

```
const obj1 = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2'
} as const;

Object.assign(obj1, { 'key1': '' });

const obj2 = {
    key3: `${obj1.key1}-test}`,
    key4: `${obj1.key2}-test`,
} as const;

console.log(obj2.key3); // "-test"
```

We expected `"val1-test"` but got something completely different. It wouldn't be safe to assume what the computed value will be.